# How to realize the two-dimensional density figures with actual observation points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Firstly, I'd like to ask you a question about data visualization.The main purpose is that I want to use the two-dimensional density Figures to represent the distribution simulated by the model, and add the actual observation points on the layer to show the quality of the model.The actual effect looks like this

[image]

Then, I have realized the two-dimensioned density figures using "stat_density_2d", like this

```
#r
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
  labs(title = "",y = "y", x = "x") +
  #geom_raster() +
  #geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(geom ="raster",aes(fill = ..density..),contour = F)
```

[image]

The simulation data is [here](https://github.com/huazai-beyond121/data/blob/master/data.csv)
and the actual observation points data is [here](https://github.com/huazai-beyond121/data/blob/master/data2.csv)

Comment: You can add the points with a `+geom_point()` term added to your `ggplot`.  It is probably best added after the `stat_density_2d` - then the points will be on top and visible!

Comment: Got it! many thanks. But I would like to ask another question, how can I achieve the kind of 0-1 change in the legend

Comment: That's a good question. I can't think of a straightforward answer, but I'm sure if you ask it as a separate question on SO, somebody will know!

Comment: You could try `fill = ..density../max(..density..)` to normalise it to a maximum of 1.

Comment: Thank you, I made another post, and it has been realized！you can refer to this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705125/two-dimensional-density-figure-changes-from-0-to-1-in-the-legend)