# two-dimensional density figure changes from 0 to 1 in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. My purpose-How to change the two-dimensional density figure in the legend from 0 to 1.
2. I have generated two variable sequence data [here](https://github.com/huazai-beyond121/data/blob/master/data.csv). 
   I have realized the two-dimensioned density figures using `stat_density_2d`, like this

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=spi,y=crop))+
  labs(title = "",y = "y", x = "x") +
  #geom_raster() +
  #geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(geom ="raster",aes(fill = ..density..),contour = F)
```

[image]

However, the legend "density" shows from 0.05 to 0.2. I want to normalize the "density" into an interval of [0,1], with 1 for the highest density and 0 for the lowest density. How do I program it, or what do I do with the raw data to get the results I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite easy, you simply change `fill = ..density..` to `fill = ..ndensity..` (note: modern usage is `stat(ndensity)`).

Default density with example data:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(density)), contour = F)
```

[image]

Density scaled to the [0-1] range:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(ndensity)), contour = F)
```

[image]

And if you explicitly want to include 0 in your legend:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(ndensity)), contour = F) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, NA))
```

This is documented under 'computed variables' of `?stat_density_2d`.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem perfectly